# SCSS: parent hover selector

Tags: css, sass

In `scss` we can use a parent selector class:

```
<div class="parent is-active">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>

.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.children {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  .is-active & {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/wx9L9jzj/2/)

How would you write a parent `hover` selector?

Comment: There is no real parent selector...what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: If user make hover on parent block, then need to change children element background. I have styles for parent and children elements in different files and want to make the same staff like this: `&:hover & {`

Comment: Is there a case for `@at-root` here....?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/wx9L9jzj/3/

**SCSS:**

```
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.children {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  
  .is-active & {
    background: red;
  }
  
  :hover > & {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Note the `:hover > &` SCSS selector that essentially looks at the parent node to determine if the child was within a `:hover` pseudo-class. This is not standard CSS and requires the SASS syntax to be compiled to standard CSS, which SASS does by rewriting the selector.

**Per [SASS documentation on the parent (&) selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector):**

> The parent selector, &, is a special selector invented by Sass that’s used in nested selectors to refer to the outer selector. It makes it possible to re-use the outer selector in more complex ways, like adding a pseudo-class or adding a selector before the parent.
>
> When a parent selector is used in an inner selector, it’s replaced with the corresponding outer selector. This happens instead of the normal nesting behavior.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call another class or pseudo element inside a selector with scss, you have to use the **&** symbol.

**Example:**

```
<div class="class-1 class-2"></div>
```

SASS

```
.class-1 {
    &.class-2 {
    }
}
```

This would compile the following CSS

```
.class-1.class-2 {
}
```

To achieve, what you're asking for, you need to do as follows:

```
.parent {
    &:hover {
        .children {
            // write the desired CSS
        }
    }

    // for the active class you write
    &.is-active {
        .children {
            // desired CSS
        }
    }
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx9L9jzj/4/) on hover.